# Why can't I select an element once it's moved into a grid element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to remove the blur effect of an image contained inside a grid element, but looks like i'm not able to modify the porperty of an element contained in a grid class.

To simplify the problem I did a simple test:
I'm successfully able to modify a class called **ppp2** when the mouse pass over **ppp** with following code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ppp").hover(function(){
    $("ppp2").css("color", "#ff00ff");
    }, function(){
    $("ppp2").css("color", "#000000");
  });
});
</script>
```

but when I move the ppp2 element inside a grid class it doesn't work anymore:

```
<div class="wgrid-container" id="Locations">
   <ppp2>
      prova<br>prova<br>prova<br>prova<br>prova<br>
   </ppp2>  
</div>
```

where **wgrid-container** is defined like this.

````
.wgrid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header header header'
    'menu menu main main main right right right'
    'menu menu footer footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}```

when i remove the display: grid; the jQuery works but of course i loose the grid :)
````

Comment: `ppp` !== `ppp2`

Comment: Yes they are two different classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be ppp2 not pop so  `$("ppp").hover(function(){` will be `$("ppp2").hover(function(){`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ppp").hover(function(){
    $("ppp2").css("color", "#ff00ff");
    }, function(){
    $("ppp2").css("color", "#000000");
  });
});
```

```css
.wgrid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header header header'
    'menu menu main main main right right right'
    'menu menu footer footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wgrid-container" id="Locations">
 <ppp>
      ppp<br>ppp<br>ppp<br>ppp<br>ppp<br>
   </ppp> 
   <ppp2>
      prova<br>prova<br>prova<br>prova<br>prova<br>
   </ppp2> 
</div>
```

Comment: Typo questions should be closed, not answered.

Comment: I have two classes: one is ppp and the other is ppp2. When I pass on ppp I'd like to have ppp2 changing color